# SQL Server  2005/2008 : find row values that exist and list that don't in my in select column condition IN()

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, if-statement, where-clause, exists

I have a single table that contain columns:

```
UserID, EmployeeID, BadgeType, HiredDate, TermDate
```

Now I need to find `userID` that are with `(gbro, qunro, 1utny, ybeiot, 4ybey)`

The 3 users (`gbro, qunro, 1utny`) exist so it is listed with respective its column info.

What if `ybeiot, 4ybey` does not exist AT ALL but still I want them listed in a separate table still but with a message that PRINTS: `User that does not exist: ybeiot;4ybey`

Help, been finding way how to do this.

I tried `JOIN` (all the joins) but it does not result to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at SQL EXISTS keyword?

Answer (score 0):

```
put all the users to be searched in a temp table or table variable @userstoSearch

select * from  @userstoSearch us left join users u
on us.UserID=u.UserID where u.userID is not null

select us.UserID from  @userstoSearch us left join users u
on us.UserID=u.UserID where u.userID is null
for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two selects. The first will list the existing values and the second lists the not existing values. You should merge these results using the [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) keyword.